# graphQL networkStatus 7 on Android

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo Client on the front side with React native, and graphQL on the backend. When I'm testing the app on an IOS emulator as usual, everything works fine. But when I run the app on my Android device, fetching fails and this.props.data has networkStatus 7 error. Something tells me it's the config of Apollo client network interface but not sure. Here's my config

```
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({uri:'http://localhost:3000/graphql'});

this.client = new ApolloClient({
 networkInterface,
 dataIdFromObject: o => o.id,
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you verify that `localhost:3000` is reachable from your Android device and it points to the GraphQL server?

Comment: it's reachable but not to graphql server

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to easily debug this by looking at the error that's returned from `ApolloClient.query` or `ApolloClient.watchQuery`. If you're using react-apollo's `graphql` higher order component, the error will be available as `data.error` in the component.

Comment: Yes it's a network request error. But there's no error on IOS.

Comment: There has to be some specific setting for android devices on Apollo client

Comment: error: [Error: Network error: Network request failed],